# Find the fundamental matrix if $A$ has an $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a differential equation
$$y'(x) = A y(x),$$
where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.
We will look for solutions of the form $y(x)=v e^{\lambda x}$, where $v$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Let $v_i$ be $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. Then, for all $i$, $v_i$'s forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $y_i(x)=v_i e^{\lambda_i x}$, $i=1,...,n$. Then $Y(x)= \left( y_1(x) ... y_n(x) \right)$ is a fundamental matrix.

Questions:

1. Why our solutions is of the form $y(x)=v e^{\lambda x}$?
2. From the eigenvalue and eigenvector, how do we come up to this form $y_i(x)=v_i e^{\lambda_i x}$, $i=1,...,n$.

I forgot the source of this problem and I have a problem understanding this idea.

Comment: The right intuitive answer here depends a little bit on where you're starting your journey. If you already know something about linear algebra then it's immediately obvious to at least try to eigendecompose your initial condition. When you do that you get a solution of the form $\sum_i c_i v_i e^{\lambda_i x}$ from what you know in the 1D case and superposition. You can try to do something analogous with the Jordan form if the matrix isn't diagonalizable.

Comment: But if you don't already know anything about linear algebra then it can be more intuitive to just think of looking for exponential solutions as an educated guess that happens to always work.

Comment: Note that they are **assuming** that the solutions are of that form. This is not always the case, it is an assumption here. **If** $v$ is an eigenvector if $A$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ then it is easy to see that if $y(t) = e^{\lambda t} v$ then $y'(t) = \lambda e^{\lambda t} v = A (e^{\lambda t} v)$ so $y$ satisfies the equation $x' = Ax$.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$ and assume we have a solution of the form $y = v e^{\lambda x}$.  Then $$ A y = Av e^{\lambda x} = \lambda v e^{\lambda x} = y' $$
since being an eigenpair means that $Av = \lambda v$.

For your second question, we hope to have a full set of eigenvectors.  That is $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$, each of which will give a linearly independent solution.  You may have to do things like multiply by the appropriate number of $x$'s if you don't have a full set of eigenvectors, so your solutions come from each of the eigenvectors.